# Make OpenCV frame non-resizable

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I am making a frame using OpenCV in Python, but the frame can be resized with the mouse, and I don't want it to be resized. I googled it, but there was nothing similar to it.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('E:/file.png')
cv2.imshow('image', im)
```

How can I alter it so that the frame cannot be resized?

Answer (score 1):

Create a window with flag CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE to restrict the window resizing. For example:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('E:/file.png')
cv2.namedWindow('image', CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow('image', im)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'winname' is not defined`

Comment: Can you give me a proper example?

Comment: `NameError: name 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' is not defined`

Comment: `cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` in Python

Comment: But there is no difference.